# How do I fix a strange browser issue in Windows 8, where only Chrome works?

Tags: windows-8, firefox, google-chrome, opera

This is extremely strange.  I like Firefox.  I have a strange issue where the only browsers that seem to work are Google Chrome, IE (the latest), and Maxthon browser.  When I try to use Firefox, Safari or Opera, I cannot browse to any site.  With Firefox it just starts trying to load the first page and then gives me the report that Firefox is not responding.  Note, I have a computer with 3rd gen Intel i7 cpu, 16GB Ram, and this happens all the time, not just when the system is under unusual heavy load.  It does the same thing in Opera too.  So, basically, I can run Chrome and the other browsers mentioned but Firefox will not respond.  IE is not quite running right either but it's somewhat intermittent.

I tried to run Windows Defender to run a virus scan but it reports, "This app has been turned off and isn't monitoring your computer.  If you're using another app... use Action Center to check that apps status."  After doing many Google searches with that exact error in the search, I kept getting solutions which said to go to Control Panel and add Windows components.  I tried that and yet among all the choices, Windows Defender was not there in any of the folders.  I then tried to uninstall every other antivirus software app and that still would not let me run Windows Defender.  I couldn't find anything telling me how to turn on Windows Defender.

Ok, so I looked to see what the best antivirus software was, by going to download.com and snapfiles.com... and filtering based on editor's rating.  It seems that Ad-aware Free Antivirus+ was the best one.  So, I'm running that and have done a full scan and some quick scans and letting it fix any problems found.

Still the problem exists with Firefox and Opera.  Does anyone have any advice?  I had uninstalled Firefox and reinstalled, and used an uninstaller that is supposed to clean up everything, including files, etc. that are not necessarily removed by uninstalling.  Then I reinstalled, which obviously didn't fix the problem.  I thought of trying that again.  I think another uninstaller that I have does a better job of really removing everything when doing an uninstall.
Should I try different anti-malware software in addition to the Ad-Aware Antivirus?
Thanks,
Bruce

Comment: If your unable to run Windows Defender and you did NOT do something to disable it, you have serious problems.  You need to find the malicious infection that exists on your computer before anything can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point have you considered 'refreshing' your Microsoft Windows 8 Operating System? Instead of prolonging the issue by trying to come up with a solution, resolve the issue within 40 minutes tops with the built-in Microsoft Windows program and 'refresh' your Windows PC.

> "Refreshing your PC reinstalls Windows and keeps your personal files
>   and settings. It also keeps the apps that came with your PC and the
>   apps you installed from the Windows Store."

Please note, if you're having problems with your PC, you can try to refresh, reset, or restore it. Refreshing your PC reinstalls Windows and keeps your personal files and settings. It also keeps the apps that came with your PC and the apps you installed from the Windows Store. Resetting your PC reinstalls Windows but deletes your files, settings, and apps—except for the apps that came with your PC. Restoring your PC is a way to undo recent system changes you've made.

**How to refresh, reset, or restore your Microsoft Windows PC**

- http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc

Comment: I probably have to contact Microsoft.  Last time I tried to install Windows with my key code that I bought, they said that I had used that Key code 5+ times.  When I upgrade my motherboard or disk drive (such as installing a SSD), it appears as if i had installed it on a different system.  Some companies are able to make it so only 1 activation is good, so if someone did install the sw on a different machine, it wouldn't work.  Anyway, they gave me a new key code and said that they wouldn't be able to do that again.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you will not be happy with the following answer, but sometimes trying to solve this kind of problem (and the research that comes with it) takes so much more than just installing a fresh copy of Windows.

If you can be sure it's a OS issue (which seems to be the case), take a deep breath and start fresh.